# What java apis are there to help with annotation processing by using reflection?

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

I`m looking to start project that needs to process annotations. I was wondering what apis are available to help with reflection and annotation processing. I know theres Apache BeanUtils but are there any others?

Answer (score 1):

[Unitils](http://www.unitils.org/apidocs/org/unitils/util/AnnotationUtils.html) and [spring](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/core/annotation/AnnotationUtils.html) have `AnnotationUtils` that might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The Java [Annotation Processing API](http://www.javabeat.net/articles/14-java-60-features-part-2-pluggable-annotation-proce-1.html) might be a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to Bozho's post there is `java.beans.ReflectionUtils` that serves as a utility class for reflectively finding methods, constuctors and fields using reflection.

There is also a `ReflectionUtils` class in `org.springframework.util` for some more advanced stuff but it is marked for internal use only. Using it against this advise you should keep in mind that it might change over time and versions.